# Hiding Parse javascript SDK files and blocking client from running js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

I'm working on a Parse web app and have run into some problems using the backbone.js based client side javascript sdk. I noticed the way I have things set up, the client can view all of my source code by simply using the dev tools to view source files and can also run code against the database (within the limits of the ACL's I've set). I've started working on rebuilding the app in cloud code using the Express.js module Parse provides so that all of my code is stored server side, but I was wondering how those using client side frameworks get around this obvious problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the issue with client-side code. **Assume any code you send to the client is hacked, broken, and tampered with.**

With JavaScript, your best bet is to use either Cloud Code and send AJAX or streaming data calls to the server, retrieve the data from the server at runtime (not super secure, but would fool some people), or accept that your code is vulnerable.

I typically work with frameworks in the MVC format, so I only expose a limited subset of the actual model via a REST API. I use both a client-side framework and a server-side framework. Any thing sensitive goes on the server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's more or less what I assumed but it's helpful to hear it from some one else. I had just assumed there must be some way to obscure source code for client side apps. Could you go into any detail about what you mean when you say you use client and server side frameworks, especially with regards to Parse? I guess this would be a good time to admit I am relatively new to full stack js in general.

Comment: So you can obscure JS on the client-side, but it is mainly renaming functions, variables, etc. Look at Google's analytics JS for an example. Parse is a great app framework, a OK database solution, and a good API. But it lacks both server-side logic and client-side logic. Server-side would be Java, Python, PHP frameworks. Client side would be AngularJS / Backbone.

Comment: Makes sense. I think using a client side solution supplemented by cloud code functions makes the most sense for my project so that's what I'll be pursuing. Thanks for the answer.